# Mapbox load only a country map

Tags: ios, mapbox

Can we create a map in mapbox, that is to be used ios, which loads only a particular country instead of the whole world? For instance I wish to load the map of UK, If I Zoom out completely i could see the whole UK but no other country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the mapbox people and they kindly directed me towards the solution, I am sharing so it may be helpful for others

https://www.mapbox.com/help/style-single-country/